# Phalcon: How to use application events and where to put them?

Tags: php, phalcon

I've been playing with the Phalcon framework for some time now, but I haven't managed to figure out how to work with application events (via the EventManager).

Specifically, I would like to create a 'boot' event, so I can run code only once per application instead of once per controller (which would be the case if I extended a ControllerBase).

The [manual](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/applications.html#application-events) gives me the syntax to use, but I still don't know how to use it and in what file I should put it.

I know I could just require a 'boot.php' file in index.php, but that isn't really an elegant solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume that you have the `index.php` file which is the entry point of your application. In that file you have code to register all the services in your application. My personal preference is to keep the `index.php` file as small as possible and put the bootstrap sequence (registering services) in a different file.

So I would have in the [index.php](https://github.com/phalcon/website/blob/master/public/index.php)

```
<?php

use \Phalcon\DI\FactoryDefault as PhDi;

error_reporting(E_ALL);
date_default_timezone_set('US/Eastern');

if (!defined('ROOT_PATH')) {
    define('ROOT_PATH', dirname(dirname(__FILE__)));
}

try {

    include ROOT_PATH . "/app/var/bootstrap.php";

    /**
     * Handle the request
     */
    $di  = new PhDi();
    $app = new Bootstrap($di);

    echo $app->run(array());

} catch (\Phalcon\Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
} catch (PDOException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

The [bootstrap.php](https://github.com/phalcon/website/blob/master/app/var/bootstrap.php) contains the functions needed to initialize all the services that your application needs. One of these services can be as follows:

```
public function initEventsManager($app)
{
    $evManager = new \Phalcon\Events\Manager();

    $app->setEventsManager($evManager);

    $evManager->attach(
        "application",
        function($event, $application) {
            switch ($event->getType()) {
                case 'boot':
                    $this->handleBoot();
                    break;
                case 'beforeStartModule':
                    $this->handleBeforeStartModule();
                    break;
                case 'afterStartModule':
                    $this->handleAfterStartModule();
                    break;
                case 'beforeHandleRequest':
                    $this->handleBeforeHandleRequest();
                    break;
                case 'afterHandleRequest':
                    $this->handleAfterHandleRequest();
                    break;
        }
    );
}
```

In your `bootstrap.php` file you should have relevant functions such as `handleBoot` `handleAfterHandleRequest` etc. that will process the code the way you need to.

The above function to register the events manager will need to be invoked with the Phalcon\Mvc\Application as a parameter. A good place to put it would be here (based on the examples)

https://github.com/phalcon/website/blob/master/app/var/bootstrap.php#L62

Comment: Hmm. This is still not quite what I'm looking for, as it requires me to rewrite/extend the standard application code. Your example is useful for figuring out how to attach the bootevent to the event manager, though. That's why I accepted this answer.

Comment: I had a tiny error with your otherwise very useful code. For further reference, if checking $event (in the switch) is not working, try $event->getType(). That method will return the correct type or event name.

Comment: To answer your previous question/comment: You don't need to extend the standard application. It is just a matter of what you are comfortable with. The examples I offered is how I did it and how we bootstrap the main phalconphp.com website.